# Какие есть лёгкие визуальные редакторы для html-файлов?

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Есть проект сайта-библиотеки с множеством html-файлов. На них есть стандартная разметка html (body, div, script и прочее) и основная текстовая часть. **Нужно получить возможность править эту текстовую часть в визуальном редакторе** (чтобы мог править простой человек - не программист). Понятное дело, этот редактор должен как бы игнорировать то, что не относится к тексту (не трогать теги body style doctype и пр).

Ставить для этого сайт на движок не вариант, т.к теряется гибкость работы с материалом (которая нужна программисту). В какую сторону можно смотреть, на каких принципах это может быть реализовано?

UPD: MS Word позволяет работать с html файлами похожим образом на тот, который требуется, но при сохранении внедряет кучу лишнего кода.

Comment: Можно взять Typora (или другой визуальный редактор для markdown), сохранять в md, конвертировать в html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Bluegriffon](http://www.bluegriffon.org/)** – действительно лёгкий редактор и позволяющий редактировать html-файлы в визуальном режиме, когда используются стили из подключенных css-файлов. Влияние на код минимально: может добавить (или подызменить) пару строк в `header` и совершить переносы в коде (последнее можно отключить в настройках).

Из особенностей, показывает в визуальном режиме, где находятся комментарии и блоки скриптов, то есть редактирующий будет их видеть.

Comment: (В конечном счёте на этом поиск визуального редактора был завершён. Пользоваться им не стали, поскольку это оказалось неудобным решением для наших задач, вместо этого была написана своя CMS, куда был интегрирован редактор TinyMCE. Однако аналогов ему найдено не было.)